# Get a JSON API extension with multiple datatypes in a List

Tags: c#, json, api, uwp

I am right now working in a uwp project that I get values from a JSON `Web API`. Inside the `API` i have multiple rooms and attributes to them, and i have no problem with reaching them.

The problem i have is how i should get the values for all the bookings on the rooms cause the bookings is in a url extension like this:

URL without bookings:

```
string url = "https://api.booking.com/api/room";
```

URL with bookings:

```
string url = "https://api.booking.com/api/room/35bf3c4d-9b5b-40fd-bcf4-a4c2c6c564bc/bookings";
```

The `Guid` is the id of a room.

The same problem i had with the images of each room but i solved that problem by doing this:

This is what i tested first but then i only got one image:

```
string url = "https://api.booking.com/api/room/35bf3c4d-9b5b-40fd-bcf4-a4c2c6c564bc/image";
```

But the i tested this and it got all the images:

```
public Uri ImageUrl => 
   new Uri( $"https://api.booking.com/api/room/{Id}/image", UriKind.Absolute );
```

So i got the id of every room i had and got the image to all the rooms, but this method don't work with the bookings cause in the bookings extension there is multiple datatypes and it is not working if i make the object a `uri`.

Hope that you understand my problem...

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Json sample of two of the rooms:

```
[
{
    "name": "Rum 1",
    "id": "a31d1fc8-df29-419c-8308-f8bc884b378e",
    "seats": 10,
    "availableFrom": null,
    "availableTo": null
  },
  {
    "name": "Rum 2",
    "id": "7defd34d-222d-4980-b28f-e616e8b9003c",
    "seats": 5,
    "availableFrom": null,
    "availableTo": null
  }
]
```

Json sample of one of the bookings:

```
[
  {
    "id": "12324a01-92b7-49f3-8d10-1def59eddd32",
    "code": 6679,
    "timeFrom": "2018-02-13T16:00:00",
    "timeTo": "2018-02-13T16:45:00",
    "note": null,
    "createdDate": "2018-02-13T10:04:14.8",
    "room": {
      "name": "Rum 2",
      "id": "7defd34d-222d-4980-b28f-e616e8b9003c",
      "seats": 10,
      "availableFrom": null,
      "availableTo": null
    }
  }
]
```

This is my class for bookings:

```
public class Bookings
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public DateTime timeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime timeTo { get; set; }
    public List<Class2> room { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the class for the rooms:

```
public class Class2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int seats { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageUrl => new Uri($"https://api.bookings.com/api/rooms/{id}/image", UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

This is how i get the bookings:

```
string booking = "https://api.booking.com/api/room/{id}/bookings";

HttpClient BookingClient = new HttpClient();

string BookingResponse = await BookingClient.GetStringAsync(booking);

var BookingData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Bookings>>(response);
```

This is where i declare the variable room and books:

```
foreach (var room in data)
{
    string id = room.id;
    string name = room.name;
    int seats = room.seats;
    Uri Img = room.ImageUrl;

    foreach (var books in BookingData)
    {
        string note = books.note;
        DateTime TimeFrom = books.timeFrom;
        DateTime TimeTo = books.timeTo;
        Class2 BookRoom = books.room;
        string BookId = books.id;
        int code = books.code;

        //if (room.Bookings.Any(a => a.timeFrom == DateTime.UtcNow))
        //{
        //    templategrid.GreenToRed();
        //}
        //else if (room.Bookings.Any(a => a.timeFrom != DateTime.UtcNow))
        //{
        //    do stuff
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is happening. Could you post more code - example of the JSON, the code where you use the images?

Comment: I updated the question, hope that will make ti clearer :) @MartinZikmund

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably in the `Bookings` class:

```
public class Bookings
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public DateTime timeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime timeTo { get; set; }
    public Class2 room { get; set; }
}
```

The `room` property is not a `List` or array according to the example JSON you have posted - it is just a single room. I also recommend you to change the name of the class `Class2` to something like `BookingRoom` to make code more readable.

To read the data from the `bookings` endpoint, you can then do

```
var bookings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bookings[]>( jsonString );
```

**Update**: I have just tested deserializing the class the same way you do and it deserializes the dates just fine:

[image: Deserializing]

I have used exactly the same classes:

```
public class Bookings
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public DateTime timeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime timeTo { get; set; }
    public Class2 room { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int seats { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageUrl => new Uri($"https://api.rumsbokning.nu/api/companies/aab96aa1-d8ca-4f74-8e35-ded190c38dd4/rooms/{id}/image", UriKind.Absolute);
}
```

**Update**:
You must get the room bookings in a loop and associate them manually:

```
foreach (var room in data)
{
   string booking = $"https://api.booking.com/api/room/{room.Id}/bookings";
   HttpClient BookingClient = new HttpClient();
   string BookingResponse = await BookingClient.GetStringAsync(booking);
   var bookings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Bookings>>(response);
   room.Bookings = bookings;
}
```

What your code is currently doing is enumerating each room and for each room it is enumerating *the same `BookingsData` variable*, which does not work, because the variable contains bookings for just one of the rooms, not for all.

Comment: Okey, i'll test your solution and come back with an answer as soon as possible :)

Comment: Check my edit, right now when i try to get `timeTo` it is just null all the time...

Comment: And `timeFrom`? It can't be null, as `DateTime` is not nullable.

Comment: when i try to get `timeFrom` i get the same error: **System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'**

Comment: This is where I get that error : `if (room.Bookings.Any(a => a.timeFrom == DateTime.UtcNow))`

Comment: Where do you set `room.Bookings`? Please add that code as well. The `null` exception is probably because `room.Bookings` is null.

Comment: Yeah, check the edit. Sorry for being unclear but i am so lost right now :(

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking time to help me! When you have `{id}` in the url it is suposed to take all the `id`:s of the `rooms` so the `BookingData` should contain bookings for all the `rooms`.

Comment: No, that is not the case. When you have a string $"{Id}" it is just a syntax instead of `string.Format`. The curly brackets are replaced with the content of variable "Id" in the current scope

Comment: Yeah thanks! now when i try `if(books.timeTo < DateTime.UtcNow)` it does something, and i have double checked it and all the timeTo is lower value than `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171994/discussion-between-luddep-and-martin-zikmund).

Comment: I have now laid in my real values to all the variables and have tested `timeFrom` and `timeTo` and their value is always `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` and I have tried multiple solutions but it won't seem to work :(

Comment: That really should not be happening. Please create a new question for this and send a link here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50850977/deserialize-datetime-from-a-web-api there you go :)