# Deserialize DateTime from a web api

Tags: c#, json, datetime, uwp, deserialization

So I have an sql database where i get values from via a json `API`.
I have som problem with deserializing the `DateTime` variables `timeFrom` and `timeTo`.

Right now all the `timeFrom` and all the `timeTo` gets tha value of:

> {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}

Witch is not the correct value...

This is a sample of one booking of a room from the json api:

```
{
    "id": "c49af34d-5479-4304-8acc-30f22a7cd1ef",
    "code": 6679,
    "timeFrom": "2018-06-13T16:00:00",
    "timeTo": "2018-06-13T16:45:00",
    "note": null,
    "createdDate": "2018-02-13T10:04:14.8",
    "room": {
      "name": "Rum 1",
      "id": "c49af34d-5479-4304-8acc-30f22a7cd1ef",
      "seats": 10,
      "availableFrom": null,
      "availableTo": null,
      "roomAttributes": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Tv",
          "icon": 62060
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Wifi",
          "icon": 61931
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

And this is how I deserialize the json:

```
string booking = "https://api.booknings.com/api/company/c49af34d-5479-4304-8acc-30f22a7cd1ef/room/{room.id}/booking";
HttpClient BookingClient = new HttpClient();
string BookingResponse = await BookingClient.GetStringAsync(booking);
var BookingData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Bookings>>(response);

foreach (var books in BookingData)
{
     string note = books.note;
     DateTime TimeFrom = books.timeFrom;
     DateTime TimeTo = books.timeTo;
     Class2 BookRoom = books.room;
     string BookId = books.id;
     int code = books.code;
}
```

This is the class where I have all the properties of the booking:

```
public class Bookings
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
    public DateTime timeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime timeTo { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    public Class2 room { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is if there is someone who knows what i am doing wrong...

Thanks in avance!

Comment: ...and createdDate is serialized correctly?

Comment: works fine for me

Comment: I don't really know. The thing is that the only thing I need in this aspect is `timeFrom` and `timeTo` @Schadensbegrenzer

Comment: @luddep- you can use newtonsoft.Json

Comment: I have downloaded the newtonsoft.Json but still it is not working... @Prany

Comment: It's working quite fine. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wycaia Which version of newton do you use?

Comment: I have 11.0.2 @Schadensbegrenzer

Comment: @luddep- Check my answer, it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json

```
        var files = JObject.Parse(YourJsonhere);
        var recList = files.SelectTokens("$..timeTo").ToList();
        string value = recList[0].ToString();
```

Comment: Inside the `Parse`, should I paste all of my Json?

Comment: Yes please paste json here or if you have json in a file then you can use stream reader. like this StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\pathToJson.json");
            string line = sr.ReadLine(); var files = JObject.Parse(line);

Comment: weeelll... I don't thing that is possible, because the json example is just one of all the bookings in ONE of the rooms and all the bookings for each room is in a separate URL extension...

Comment: how were you earlier planing to use that in your existing code. I mean using individual URL to capture?

Comment: No, right now i have this `"https://api.bookings.com/api/company/f8b0a9a3-3f87-4c80-bca3-3b6209e7c120/rooms/{room.id}/bookings"` so it takes all the the bookings for each room.

Comment: In your code what does BookingResponse contain ? Json ?

Comment: It sends a GET request to the `Uri` so when debugging the sring `BookingResponse` is just saying that it is an array cause it says `[]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173119/discussion-between-prany-and-luddep).